# Solution for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

Need to make a form for *competitions* **category** with custom inputs. It should take all values from **Information** table and build the inputs, but the tricky part is that it should be saved to **Category_informations** table.

```
class Competition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
  has_many :informations
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :competetion
  has_many :category_informations
  has_many :information, through: competition
end

class CategoryInformation
  belongs_to :catagory
  belongs_to :information
end

class Information < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :competetion
  has_many :category_informations
end
```

Competition -> name

Category -> name, competition_id

Information -> name, competition_id

Category_informations -> value, category_id, information_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Simple Form aims to be as flexible as possible while helping you with powerful components to create your forms.

Let's take a simple example:

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :parts , inverse_of: :machine
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
# name:string
belongs_to :machine
end
```

With these models, we can use simple_form to update the machine and its associated parts in a single form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @machine do |m| %>
  <%= m.simple_fields_for :parts do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For 'new' action, build the nested model from the controller:

```
class MachinesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @machine = Machine.new
  @machine.parts.build
 end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

See:
https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

https://rubyplus.com/articles/3681-Complex-Forms-in-Rails-5

Also, check out the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem.