# How to pass an account_id through a nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms

I'm trying to set up a nested form in rails and both the parent and child objects in the form need to have an "Account ID" so that they are both scoped to the current user's account, but I can't figure out how to pass the current user's Account ID for the child object through the nested form. I keep getting a validation error of "Account id must be present" for the nested object.

The parent form is "Product" and I'm trying to nest "Options" into the Product.new form.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@product.options.account_id = current_user.account.id
```

But it's not working.

Here is the Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true

  validates :account_id,  presence: true
  validates :name,        presence: true, length: { maximum: 120 }
end
```

And options model:

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :product

  has_many :option_values, dependent: :destroy

  validates :account_id,  presence: true
  validates :name,        presence: true,
                          length: { maximum: 60 }
end
```

Here's how I'm nesting "Options" into the Product form:

```
<%= form.fields_for :options do |builder| %>
    <fieldset class='form-group'>
      <%= builder.label :name, 'Add option(s)' %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>
      <small id="optionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        (e.g. "Sizes" or "Color")
      </small>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
```

And here is my ProductsController:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :restrict_access

  def index
    @products = Product.where(:account_id => current_user.account.id).all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.options.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @account = current_user.account
    @product = @account.products.build(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_product
      if Product.find(params[:id]).account_id == current_user.account.id
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      else
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      end
    end

    def restrict_access
      if index
        authorize @products
      else
        authorize @product
      end
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:account_id, :name,
                                      options_attributes: [:id, :account_id, :name ])
    end
end
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476498/10895713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can pass a hidden_field with form and nested_form as given below: -

```
<%= form_for @product do |form|%>
  <%= form.fields_for :options do |builder| %>
      <fieldset class='form-group'>
        <%= builder.label :name, 'Add option(s)' %>
        <%= builder.text_field :name %>
        <small id="optionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
          (e.g. "Sizes" or "Color")
        </small>
        <%=builder.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id%>
      </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id%>
<%end%>
```

Other than this you can set account_id at the controller

```
  def new
    #@product = Product.new
    @product = current_user.account.products.new
    @product.options.build(account_id: current_user.account.id)
  end
```

Comment: It seems like setting the ID at the controller instead of in the view is a better way to do this, but I couldn't get that to work. Adding `<%= form.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id%>` to the form worked though!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to add a hidden field into both forms:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

So in your case, for the options form, something like:

```
  <%= form.fields_for :options do |builder| %>
    <fieldset class='form-group'>
      <%= builder.label :name, 'Add option(s)' %>
      <%= builder.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_account.id %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>
      <small id="optionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        (e.g. "Sizes" or "Color")
      </small>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
```

This will give you access to the `[:option][:account_id]` param, which will match the current user's.